# What to do next to display data onto HTML using JS after acquiring data from database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

I am doing an exercise to create a small website that display data to HTML from PostgreSQL using TypeScript or Javascript. After I retrieved the data, I don't know what to do next to display the data onto HTML in a readable fashion, any idea on how I should go about doing it through JS?

```
app.get("/usersinfo", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const userinfo = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM usersinfo");
    res.json(userinfo.rows);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}});
```

After setting up a localhost at port 5000, I see the following as an array but I am not quite sure what to do next to organise it.

> [{"id":1,"username":"john","password":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","coinamount":100,"create_at":"2021-04-01T14:29:52.103Z","last_login":"2021-04-01T14:29:52.103Z","google_access_token":null}]

Comment: what does your current html look like?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili it looks exactly like the above array, a blank white page with that array on it when I access localhost:5000/usersinfo

Answer (score 1):

Basically Say you have a simple html like

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Then you use javascript to do this

```
let data = [{"id":1,"username":"john","password":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","coinamount":100,"create_at":"2021-04-01T14:29:52.103Z","last_login":"2021-04-01T14:29:52.103Z","google_access_token":null}]
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const ul = document.createElement('ul')
const li = document.createElement('li')

for (let item of data){
   const username  = document.createElement('li')
    username.textContent = item.username
    li.append(username)
    const password  = document.createElement('li')
    password.textContent = item.password
    li.append(password)
    const email  = document.createElement('li')
    email.textContent = item.email
    li.append(email)
    const lastLogin  = document.createElement('li')
    lastLogin.textContent = item.last_login
    li.append(lastLogin)
  
}


ul.appendChild(li)
container.appendChild(ul)
```

This is just rough idea of DOM manipulation. You should read more about this in relation to using JavaScript for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But the array is not a hard coded, it is coming from the data stored on a database from a PostgreSQL table. After I have done app.get, I am not sure how to get started on using innerHTML to manipulate the data from a PostgreSQL table.

Comment: the array doesn not need to hard coded. You retrieve the array after fetching it from the backend  with REST API and do the what i showed you.

Comment: I will have a read, thank you for the tip!